# A detailed demostration of $Du=0\quad \mbox{a.e }\Longrightarrow u\equiv C\quad\mbox{a.e}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is about exercise number 11 of section 5.10 of the text Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition. This is an exercise that has been posed by other people on this page, but I have noticed that the demos that are given lack some details, rather they are about sketches.Although I still have some concerns, I will try to demonstrate this exercise in detail, while asking for your cooperation to clarify my concerns in the lines highlighted in bold below:

**Exercise.** Suppose $U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is open and connected, and $u\in W^{1,p}(U)$  satisfies $$Du=0\quad\mbox{a.e in }U. $$
Prove $U$ is constant a.e in $U$.

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon>0$. Consider the function $$u^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon *u,$$
by Theorem 7 of appendix C.5 of the book Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition (properties of mollifiers), $u^\epsilon$ is $C^\infty$ in the set $$U_\epsilon=\{\mathbf{x}\in U:\mbox{d}{(\mathbf{x},\partial U)}>\epsilon\}.$$
Note that $U_\epsilon$ is open, since if $y\in U_\epsilon$, that is, $$y\in U\quad\mbox{and}\quad\mbox{d}(\mathbf{y}, \partial U)> \epsilon,$$
By doing $r=\mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\partial U)-\epsilon>0$, it's easy to see that $B(\mathbf{y},r)\subset U_\epsilon$. In fact, let $\mathbf{w}\in B(\mathbf{y},r) $, then \begin{align*}
    \mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{w}) <r & \Longleftrightarrow \mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{w})<\mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\partial U)-\epsilon\\ & \Longleftrightarrow \mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{w}) <\mbox{d}(\mathbf{y},\mathbf{w})+\mbox{d}(\mathbf{w},\partial U)-\epsilon \\ & \Longleftrightarrow \mbox{d}(\mathbf{w},\partial U)>\epsilon.\end{align*}
So $\mathbf{w}\in U_\epsilon$, and $ U_\epsilon$ is open. On the other hand, by the proof of Theorem 1 from section 5.3 of the book Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition (local approximation by smooth functions), we have that
\begin{align*}
Du^\epsilon=\eta_\epsilon * Du\quad\mbox{on } U_\epsilon,
\end{align*}
where $\eta_\epsilon $ is the standard mollifier. Since ***$Du=0$ a.e in $U $, it follows from the previous line that $Du^\epsilon=0 $ a.e in $U_\epsilon $, O well, $u$ is constant in every connected component of $U_\epsilon $*** ***(is it correct to state this? if yes, why?)***. Now let $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in U $, since $U$ is open and connected, so this is connected by paths, there is a path $\Gamma\subset U$ that connects to $\mathbf{x} $ with $\mathbf{y}$. Let $\delta=\min_{\mathbf{z}\in\Gamma} \mbox{d}(\mathbf{z},\partial U) $, that is, $\delta$ is the minimum distance between the points of $\Gamma $ and the boundary of $U$. For the choice of  $\delta$, for all $\epsilon<\delta $, the path $\Gamma$ is contained in $ U_\epsilon $. Therefore, given any two points of $U$, for all $\epsilon<\delta $, these can be connected by a path contained in $ U_\epsilon $, in other words $U_\epsilon $ is connected by paths, thus $U_\epsilon $ is connected. It follows that $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y} $ are in the same connected component $U_\epsilon $, ***so $ u^\epsilon(\mathbf{x})=u^\epsilon(\mathbf{y})$ is constant*** ***(it is correct to state that if $Du^\epsilon=0$ a.e, then $u^\epsilon$ is constant in each open connected $U_\epsilon$? why?)***. Finally, by hypothesis $u\in W^{1,p} (U) $, therefore, by Theorem 7 of appendix C.5 of the book Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition (properties of mollifiers) ***implies that $u^\epsilon\longrightarrow u $ a.e in $U$ as $\epsilon \to 0 $, therefore $ u $ is constant a.e in $ U $*** ***(Why if $u^\epsilon$ is constant a.e in every connected component $U_\epsilon$ and $u^\epsilon\longrightarrow u$ a.e in $U$, then $u$ is constant a.e in $U$?).***

***Observations:*** This demostration uses some results and notation from the text Lawrence C. Evans - Partial Differential Equations_ Second Edition.

***Definitions:*** **(i)** Define $\eta\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by
$$\eta(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}C\exp\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right), & \mbox{if }|x|<1\\0, & \mbox{if } |x|\geq 1\end{array}\right.$$
the constant $C>0$  selected so that $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}}\eta\,dx=1$.

**(ii)** For each $\epsilon>0$, set $$\eta_\epsilon(x):=\frac{1}{\epsilon^n}\eta\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right).$$

We call $\eta$ standard mollifier. The functions $\eta_\epsilon$ are $C^\infty$ and satisfy $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\eta_\epsilon\,dx=1, \mbox{spt}(\eta_\epsilon)\subset B(0,\epsilon).$$
spt denotes support.

**(iii)** $d$ denotes the distance function associated with the metric of the space in question.

**(iv)** $*$ denotes convolution.

**(v)** $W^{1,p}$ denotes Sobolev space.

**The reason for the different questions raised above is that I have researched and found different solutions for this exercise, more like demonstration sketches, but these are not very detailed. In the end, after understanding and solving most of the above demo on my own, I was left with the concerns raised.**

Comment: I'm not clear what obstruction you see to applying the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_in_several_variables).  Connected components of $\Bbb{R}^n$ are path connected.  Any two points in one component have a path between them avoiding the measure zero set on which $Du \neq 0$, so ...

Comment: $U_{\epsilon}$ need not be connected. Indeed, there exists open, connected $U$ such that $U_{\epsilon}$ is disconnected for *any* $\epsilon>0$. However, for each given $x, y \in U$ you can find $\epsilon>0$ such that both $x$ and $y$ are contained in the same connected component of $U_{\epsilon}$.

Comment: First, you have $Du^{\varepsilon}=0$ *everywhere* on $U_{\varepsilon}$, not just a.e. This is easily seen by computing the integral defining the convolution $\eta_{\varepsilon}\ast Du$ and using $Du = 0$ a.e. Alternatively, you may use the fact that  $u^{\varepsilon}$ is smooth on $U_{\varepsilon}$ and hence its derivatives are continuous on $U_{\varepsilon}$. For your second question, use the fact that any $C^1$ function $v$ defined on an open, connected set $V$ statisfying $Dv = 0$ must be constant. (This is an application of the fundamental theorem of line integrals.)

Comment: For your last question, instead of investigating the limit of $u^{\varepsilon}$ on all of $U$, fix an open ball $B$ satisfying $\operatorname{dist}(B,\partial U)>0$ (so that $B \subseteq U_{\varepsilon_0}$ for some $\varepsilon_0>0$) and then study the limit of $u^{\varepsilon}$ on $B$. Since each $u^{\varepsilon}$ is constant on $B$, its a.e.-limit must be constant a.e. in $B$. This shows that $u$ is "locally constant a.e." in $U$. Now show that this together the connectivity of $U$ imply that $u$ is constant a.e. in $U$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee In your second answer, you state "Alternatively, you may use the fact that $u^\epsilon$ is smooth on $U_\epsilon$ and hence its derivatives are continuous on $U_\epsilon$" and it has already been shown that $u^\epsilon$ is constant in each connected component, then, for your statement to be true, $U_\epsilon$ must be one of such connected components, but the latter is true because $\epsilon<\delta$. I am right?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "your statement" and why you are talking about connected components. My comment about $Du^{\varepsilon}$ being identically zero is a local statement (as is the concept of the derivative) that does not concern any connectivity structure of $U_{\varepsilon}$. Are you actually talking about my comment regarding your second question? In that case, it is indeed true that $u^{\varepsilon}$ is constant on each connected component of $U_{\varepsilon}$ but we don't know yet whether $u^{\varepsilon}$ is constant on all of $U_{\varepsilon}$.

Comment: @Sangchul Lee Thank you for your contributions and clarifications.

Comment: Glad it helped! As the last comment, note that we may have considered all your argument in a fixed open ball $B$ such that $B\subset U$ and $\operatorname{dist}(B,\partial U)>0$ rather than in all of $U$. Then by taking advantage of all the nice properties of open balls, you can conclude that $u$ is constant a.e. in $B$ without worrying about topology of the domain. (The rationale behind this approach is that "constant-ness" is more of a local property than a global property, especially when the domain is connected.)